# changing the keys

Tags: electrical, starting, automatic-transmission, volvo

My mechanic lost the keys to my S80, 1998 model.  And then replace it with another key yet it still cannot start because he said there's a code needed to reset the new key so far the automobile electricians in my are  don't know what to do.  and really love the car what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Tell them to get it programmed? I mean seriously, they lost the key so they need to get their act together and call in an expert who can get it programmed.

Comment: What market are you in? Is the car fitted with an immobilizer? AFAIK The code is supplied when you purchase the key and you need OE software to write to the CEM. I don't think you need an LSID to do this either.